# Wifi suddenly stopped working on my dell inspiron n5010 using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I have been using WiFi for many days,but today in network manager i dont see enable wifi option.I did press wifi toggle many times before wifi stopped working.Previously available networks were shown to me,now no network extension found is shown.

There is no output for

> lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 && rfkill list.

**Output of**

> lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730/M96 [Mobility Radeon HD 4650/5165]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

**and output of**

> lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:641d Microdia 1.3 MPixel Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 && rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 reponse for lspci -knn is 00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0044] (rev 18)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0447]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port [8086:0045] (rev 18)
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller [8086:3b64] (rev 06)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0447]
 Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Contr

Comment: and there is no response after grep Net -A2 && rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please don't add a comment to provide additional informations, but rather [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/637731/edit) the question as Pilot6 suggested you; also please add the **full** output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 && rfkill list`, which has been cutted due to the limit to the number of characters in comments.

Comment: Why did you split the command in two?

Comment: @pilot6 there is no reply for lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 && rfkill list ,so i split the command in two's .

Comment: What is your wifi? Built in or a usb dongle? Either way post `lspci` an `lsusb` TO YOUR QUESTION NOT TO COMMENTS PLEASE.

Comment: @pilot6 plz help.

Comment: Network adapter disconnected or broken.

Comment: Are you perfectly sure thats a hardware issue.

Comment: and plz unhold the question

Comment: Neither the PCI nor the USB bus detect a network adapter. This points strongly towards a broken, disconnected or disabled (in the BIOS configuration) device, as Pilot6 said before me. As such, your question is not related to Ubuntu but purely a hardware issue.

Comment: Try to boot with Ubuntu LiveUSB. Does network adapter show? Sometimes this happens when kernel image is corrupter. It happened to me once.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command in terminal `sudo rfkill list all` and see if there are anything softblocked. 
If you see the wireless Lan is softblocked, then type `sudo rfkill unblock all`.

Comment: there is no output for rfkill list all